# javascriptRouting in Play! Scala

Tags: javascript, scala, intellij-idea, playframework

So I've been struggling with the javascript routing in scala Play!
I've added the routes in my routes file:

```
GET        /javascriptRoutes              controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes
```

and this is the route I want to add to the javascriptRoutes

```
GET        /winkelwagen/add/:id           controllers.Application.addProductToWinkelwagen(id:Int)
```

Then when I try to add the code for the generating of the javascript in my controller it says it can't resolve javascript (from routes.javascript)

```
def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
   import routes.javascript._
   Ok(
      Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
        routes.javascript.Application.addProductToWinkelwagen()
      )
   ).as("text/javascript")
}
```

I've added these to the source classes in project structure but that didn't work:

```
 target/scala-XXX/classes_managed
 target/scala-XXX/src_managed/main
```

I'm using IntelliJ Idea professional.

I hope someone can help me,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with routes.javascript.Application.addProductToWinkelwagen.
No () at the end.